# MySql database design - which table structure would be better?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am working on a mysql database and would like to know which of these two table structures is better in terms of performance.

Structure 1; two tables with lots of common fields

```
table1(file)   : id, userid, parentid, name, desc, tags, public, dateadded, datemodified, linkid, domain, url, snapshot
table2(folder): id, userid, parentid, name, desc, tags, public, dateadded, datemodified, hasSubFolders, noOfItems, noOfViews
```

Structure 2; three tables with all the common fields put in a different table

```
table1(main)   : id, userid, parentid, objectid, objecttype(file or folder), name, desc, tags, public, dateadded, datemodified
table2(file)   : id (objectid), linkid, domain, url, snapshot
table3(folder) : id (objectid), hasSubFolders, noOfItems, noOfViews
```

Comment: Structure 1 is better.

Comment: I would choose structure 2 because file and folder have many common things and it would be easier to search. Performance would be better in structure 1 however if you would like to search both in files and folders at the same time probably performance would be better for structure 2

Comment: @MinhNguyen With that absolute a statement, I'd hope for some kind of explanation why...?

Comment: @MinhNguyen I agree some explanation on that statement would help a lot.

Comment: Would you edit into the question a description of what your tables are for? If they are for a hierarchical data structure, look at the Nested Set algorithm - it is quite fast in terms of reading structures, adding nodes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use neither of them but something similar to the first example. There are a lot of common columns in the two tables. Therefore, two tables would have to be accessed just for a listing command (`ls` in UNIX, `dir` ind Windows).
Also, there are hints to the data-types in the column-names which is bad practice:

Instead, use one table: fsys_entries:

```
id, is_directory, parentid, name, desc, tags, public, added, modified, linkid, url, snapshot
```

With this structure it would be possible to create files and directories within **files** but with the correct restrictions from the code that is not a problem.

EDIT: In a real file-system a directory **is** a file with a directory-flag to it. So from that perspective its not too bad and it allows a more similar treatment as compared to a real file-system.

P.S.: As an advanced feature i would store the sharing-information (is the file/directory public? what link refers to it?) in a different table (which is just best practice).

Comment: The hints were just so the people on stackoverflow would understand the contents better. Anyway if we use the same table it would look like this: "id, is_directory, parentid, name, desc, tags, public, added, modified, linkid, domain, url, snapshot, hasSubFolders, noOfItems, noOfViews". I need all fields so please dont remove them. A single table would result in a lot of wasted space, no?

Comment: What do you need the fields `hasSubFolders` and `noOfItems` for? And why do you think that a single table would result in wasted space? As said, if you move the distinct fields (distinct of file and directory) to other tables you actually save space.

Answer (score 0):

If it performs comparably to the flat structure1, I'd go for Structure2 after renaming "main" to "FileSystemObject" or something more telegraphic.

The disadvantage is that you need joins for accessing the full information on any given FSO and this makes indexing more difficult (not sure if mysql supports indexed views nowadays).

In case of doubt, populate sample tables and benchmark.